# Getting null pointer exception in void method when using spy in junit testing

Tags: junit

i need to test 'tableInfo' method of Service class

Here is my junit test script:

```
class JUnitTest extends Specification {

Service service
Table table = GroovyMock(Table)


def spy = Spy(Service){
    getTable() >> table
        }

def setup() {
    service = new Service(                
            table: table
            )
}

def "when table contains information"() {

    given:
    spy.internalMethod(*_) >> [Bean.BEAN_SUCCESS]
    table.getUnits(*_) >> {}        
    Response response = new Response()


    when:
    spy.tableInfo(.....)


    then:
    response.status == 0
    response.error == []

}
```

Question: I am getting null pointer exception in table.getUnits as below

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUnits() on
>   null object"

Please help me out of this

Comment: check where you getting a null object and don't call the method getUnits(), when null object returns.

Comment: I am getting null object in 'table' class. I am having table.getUnits() invocation in the method which i want to test. So invocation of that method is necessary right

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method every time. But need aware of exception means, simply check the condition before calling table.getUnits() method like below.

```
 if(table.getUnits!=null)
   table.getUnits();
```

Comment: I want that table.getUnits() method to be executed and it should not be null..  why i am getting null in the class 'table'? do u have any idea?

Comment: I mocked the class 'table' using groovymock. so it should not go inside that method and i should not get null

Comment: if you want table.getUnits() method executed every time, then you check the return type object from getUnits() should not be null. If null object is returned from getUnits() function, then sure the exception  occurs. Don't store or return NULL object in table.

Comment: table.getUnits() method's return type is void. So only i wrote like  table.getUnits(*_) >> {}